# Computing the sum of datetime intervals between rows within individuals (R)

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I would like to mutate a new column that groups by `ID` and sum up the intervals between each of the sessions. Interval is defined as the difference between `End` time and its subsequent `Start` time. For example, for ID 1, this will be the sum of (`2021-07-11 05:55:00` - `2021-07-11 01:14:00` = 281mins) and (`2021-07-11 11:08:00` - `2021-07-11 08:09:00` = 179mins) which will be 460.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), Start = structure(c(1625931780, 
1625954100, 1625972880, 1625505720, 1625517480, 1625526900), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "Singapore"), End = structure(c(1625937240, 
1625962140, 1625981580, 1625513640, 1625523300, 1625531880), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "Singapore"), n = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

  ID               Start                 End n
1  1 2021-07-10 23:43:00 2021-07-11 01:14:00 3
2  1 2021-07-11 05:55:00 2021-07-11 08:09:00 3
3  1 2021-07-11 11:08:00 2021-07-11 13:33:00 3
4  2 2021-07-06 01:22:00 2021-07-06 03:34:00 3
5  2 2021-07-06 04:38:00 2021-07-06 06:15:00 3
6  2 2021-07-06 07:15:00 2021-07-06 08:38:00 3
```

Desired:

```
  ID               Start                 End n sumIntervals
1  1 2021-07-10 23:43:00 2021-07-11 01:14:00 3          460
2  1 2021-07-11 05:55:00 2021-07-11 08:09:00 3          460
3  1 2021-07-11 11:08:00 2021-07-11 13:33:00 3          460
4  2 2021-07-06 01:22:00 2021-07-06 03:34:00 3          124
5  2 2021-07-06 04:38:00 2021-07-06 06:15:00 3          124
6  2 2021-07-06 07:15:00 2021-07-06 08:38:00 3          124
```

***Note:*** Start and End are in `POSIXct` and the number of sessions within each `ID` is not constant, so it can be any number of `n`. `n=3` is used here for illustration.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `n` is not needed once we do a grouping by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can take the `lead` of 'Start' after grouping by 'ID', use `difftime` to get the difference in 'mins' from the 'End' and `sum` the `integer` converted values

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
      group_by(ID) %>%
      mutate(new = sum(as.integer(difftime(lead(Start), End, 
             units = 'mins')), na.rm = TRUE) ) %>%
      ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
     ID Start               End                     n   new
  <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <int> <int>
1     1 2021-07-10 23:43:00 2021-07-11 01:14:00     3   460
2     1 2021-07-11 05:55:00 2021-07-11 08:09:00     3   460
3     1 2021-07-11 11:08:00 2021-07-11 13:33:00     3   460
4     2 2021-07-06 01:22:00 2021-07-06 03:34:00     3   124
5     2 2021-07-06 04:38:00 2021-07-06 06:15:00     3   124
6     2 2021-07-06 07:15:00 2021-07-06 08:38:00     3   124
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain what lead does? Read the documentation and not sure what it is doing.

Comment: @TYL Suppose you have `v1 <- 1:5; lead(v1)#[1]  2  3  4  5 NA# shift by default `n = 1` thus the next row is shifted to the current element.  Notice the last element is filled by default NA.  Thus, when we do the `difftime`, we get `NA` for those last row in the group, which is removed with `na.rm = TRUE` in `sum`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!